# background image is not displaying

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

I am trying to display a background image in my CSS and have used the relative path to the image.  I have tried using different browsers but nothing seems to work.
Below is my HTML.

```
<header>
  <h2><a href="#">Rachel Doyle Studio</a></h2>
  <nav>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Embroidery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </nav>
</header>
<section class="thimble">
  <div class="background-image" style="background-image: url(assets/img/art-arts-and-crafts-bright-colours-2564890.jpg)"></div>

  <div class="thimble-content-area">
    <h1>Rachel Doyles Studio</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

and below is the CSS styling for the class of background-image.

```
.thimble background-image {

position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-size: cover;
z-index: -1;
}
```

I have attached a picture of the structure of my files.
[image: structure of project]

Why is it doing this even though I have the correct path to jpeg.

Comment: Why is your z-index  -1 ?

Comment: .thimble background-image.  You need a . in front f background-image.  It is a class.

Comment: Probably better to not use that as a class name to avoid confusion really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.thimble .background-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h2><a href="#">Rachel Doyle Studio</a></h2>
  <nav>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Embroidery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </nav>
</header>
<section class="thimble">
  <div class="background-image"></div>
  <div class="thimble-content-area">
    <h1>Rachel Doyles Studio</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a dot before *background-image* class name:

```
.thimble .background-image {

position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-size: cover;
z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add **../** to the path you're specifying

`<div class="background-image" style="background-image: url(../assets/img/art-arts-and-crafts-bright-colours-2564890.jpg)"></div>`

This should work now..

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code given, I don't think you need a separate div for the background image, either. You don't need to position it if you put the background image on .thimble directly:

```css
.thimble {
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="thimble" style="background-image: url(assets/img/art-arts-and-crafts-bright-colours-2564890.jpg)">
  <div class="thimble-content-area">
    <h1>Rachel Doyles Studio</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```